# Video Bug after a fresh installation

Tags: 10.10, graphics, login-screen, ati

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 (I'm brand new to Ubuntu) on my laptop. I seem to have a video bug that I don't know how to deal with.

When the log-in screen comes up, the boxes are way off in the corner of the screen (partially off it). When I enter my password, the screen goes black for a few seconds, then returns to the login screen.

I can open a Terminal window and enter my login info that way. When I go back to Gnome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or whatever) it shows me as "logged in" but I still can't get to the desktop.

If anyone has any advice, I'd love to hear it--just try to use simple language, please, since I really don't know Linux at all yet!

I'm running an Averatec 3700 Series:
Mobile AMD Sempron 3000+
512 MB DDR, 80 GB HDD

After looking at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15072/only-able-to-login-to-failsafe-gnome) I tried going in through Failsafe mode (took me a while to figure out the hold-shift-while-booting thing >_<) and playing around with the resolution. Setting a somewhat wider resolution did seem to fix things so that I can log into regular GNOME, I think. I'm not sure if this fix will persist, but it seems like it might!

Comment: From the terminal login and check the file .xsession-errors on your home dir, it may have some clue about the problem. Also please provide your graphics card information.

Comment: Do you have an external monitor connected (even if not powered on)?

It sounds like it's not detecting the screen resolution correctly. What graphics card/chip does the laptop have?

Comment: No external monitor connected. I'm almost positive the graphics chip is integrated rather than a separate card. The VGA Controller the lspci command returns is: VIA Technologies K8M800 K8N800 K8N00A.

Comment: how did you know how to switch to a tty if you are "new to linux"? in any case, just leave it at the current resolution and it should be fine.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).